# Extract persian and english characters between HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, tags

would someone help me to make regx for this HTML tag?

```
<h1 class="c-product__title">
    هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7
                <span>HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree</span></h1>
```

I want to extract **" هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7 "** and **" HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree "**
thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use a regular expression? Have you considered using HTML Agility Pack or Linq to XML?

Comment: Will `<h1 class="c-product__title">`  or `<span>` change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using regular expressions

```
string html = @"<h1 class=""c-product__title"">
    هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7
                <span>HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree</span></h1>";

string h1Start = @"<h1.*?>"; // h1 tag, with or without attributes
string spanStart = @"<span.*?>"; // span tag, with or without attributes
string spanEnd = @"</span>"; // span closing tag
string text = @"\s*(.+)\s*"; // there MIGHT be whitespace before and/or after the text
var regex = new Regex($"{h1Start}{text}{spanStart}{text}{spanEnd}");

Match match = regex.Match(html);

if (match.Success)
{
    string persianText = match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
    string englishText = match.Groups[2].Value.Trim();
}
```

## Alternative solution - using HtmlAgilityPack

In think that in this particular case [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) is a better option than a regular expression in order to parse an HTML fragment.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace HtmlAgilityPackDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"<h1 class=""c-product__title"">
    هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7
                <span>HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree</span></h1>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var text = (from node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes
                let textNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//text()") // selects the text 
                let spanNode = node.SelectSingleNode("span")
                select new 
                {
                    PersianText = textNode.InnerText.Trim(),
                    EnglishText = spanNode.InnerText.Trim()
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = @"<h1 class=""c-product__title"">هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7<span>HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree</span></h1>";
var regex = new Regex(@"product__title"">(?<farci>.+)<span>(?<english>.+)</span>");
var match = regex.Match(source);
```

This will return 3 Groups, the first a match for the whole regex, then 2 more, one called farci with the Persian, the second called english with the English version.

It only works if it is all on the same line.  If you have linebreaks then it won't work.

If you can its probably easier treating the html as xml and using Linq as then linebreaks are not an issue.

Comment: Given OP's sample HTML, I would assume there will be some whitespace (including line breaks etc) between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the HTMLTag as String in your C# Code you could try to use the .split() method to extrad the part you want / need. For Example:

```
String htmlTag = " < h1 class=\"c-product__title\">    هندزفری بلوتوث مدل HBQ-I7                <span> HBQ-I7 Bluetooth Handsfree</span></h1>";
string[] htmlTagSplitted = htmlTag.Split('<');
string[] htmlTagSplitted2 = new string[20];
string[] htmlTagSplitted3 = new string[20];          
htmlTagSplitted2 = htmlTagSplitted[1].Split('>');
htmlTagSplitted3 = htmlTagSplitted[2].Split('>');

Console.WriteLine(htmlTagSplitted2[1] + htmlTagSplitted3[1]);
```

htmlTagSplitted2[1] contains the first part of the String you wanted and htmlTagSplitted3[1] the 2nd part. I know this isn't Regex and neither pretty syntax, but it does it's job :-D

Best Regards Nico!

Comment: Wow looking at the other answers, I'm insta regretting my post :facepalm: nonetheless it works ^^

Comment: Parsing the string like that is more error-prone, in case the input html changes (line breaks, spacing etc). Your code is also less readable IMO... The hard part is sometimes to find the right tool for the right job! But hey, it's still a good exercise trying to do it with String.Split ;-)

Comment: Thank you for that supportive Feedback! :-) I was using String.Split a couple of times in my Programmes I wrote so far, so I thought it may fit hehe. I hope I'll be able to use more improved solutions like the one u suggested to OP in the future hehe! :-)